# Nous autres (Balzac)

Tags: adjectifs-indefinis

> Voici ce qui nous tue, nous autres petits détaillants. (Balzac)

Quel est le rôle de autres ici ? Si présence est-elle obligatoire ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "personal pronoun + autres" is used to emphasise how a particular group of people contrast sharply with others in some specific way.

In conversation, I'd say, for instance:

> Je ne sais pas ce qu'il en est pour (**vous autres**,) **les filles**, mais **nous autres**, **les gars**, on n'est pas passionné de la mode et de tout ce qui est *fashion* tant que ça...

So in your example, something delivers the coup de grâce to **us**, who are in the already struggling **retail business** – as opposed to other fields of business.

Answer (score 3):

*Nous autres*, du latin *nos alteros* est un *nous* exclusif ou renforcé (nous en tant que groupe, communauté), qui s'oppose à *vous* (*vous autres*) et pas à *ils*/*eux*.

Dans certaines langues comme l'espagnol, l'occitan et le catalan, il a même supplanté *nous*: *nosotros/nosaltres/nosautres*, *vosotros/vosaltres/vosautres*.

La français canadien utilise encore beaucoup *nous autres* (*nous-aut'*), *vous autres* et même *eux-autres*.

Comment: Cela semble être une tendance internationale; l'usage familier de « on » en français se fait couramment à la place de ce qui devrait être « nous ».